# How do I call a button function when the button is not being pressed

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ibaction

I have an IBAction connected to a button, and I wanted to know if there is any way to run that function even if the button is not being pressed. This is what I tried...

Note: I am using swift for this project.

```
//I get an error when I type this code?
self.buttonPressed()

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("Called Action")

}
```

Comment: What error? In run-time or build error?

Comment: You need to pass a "sender" argument. The convention is that methods begin with a lowercase letter, classes with an uppercase letter.

Comment: what sender argument do i pass?

Comment: If `sender` is not used in the action you can pass any object, `self` is common. If `sender` is used you must pass an object that is acceptable to the action.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make your sender argument optional and pass nil to ButtonPressed.

```
self.ButtonPressed( nil )


@IBAction func ButtonPressed( sender: AnyObject? ) {
    println("Called Action")
}
```

Answer (score 10):

One way would be to link your button up to its respective interface builder button and pass it into your function when you call it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourButton: UIButton!

self.buttonPressed(yourButton)

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Called Action")
}
```

Alternatively, define your function like so, then you'll be able to call your method the same way as you did before:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject? = nil) {
    print("Called Action")
}

// Call your method like this
self.buttonPressed()

// or this
self.buttonPressed(sender: nil)
```

Comment: @satachito Yeah, I'm really liking optional parameters in swift! Nice and clean code :)

Comment: The '= nil' didn't work for me. What does that do exactly, btw?

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer the '= nil' will only work if the type is defined as optional (the ? at the end of AnyObject). It basically means that if the method is called without any parameters it will by default set `sender` to nil. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Chackle That actually makes more sense. I was trying to pass nil to the call, maybe that's why it wasn't working. All I have to do is call the function without passing any parameters, and it will automatically send in nil, right?

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer That's exactly correct! :) Nice and clean, isn't it?

Comment: @Chackle, it is pretty sweet, can't wait to try it out!

Answer (score 2):

Your `ButtonPressed` function needs an argument `sender` and yet you're not passing any when you call it. However, if you're doing this programatically, then you obviously don't have a `sender`.

Two ways to get around this:

- Make the sender parameter an optional (`AnyObject?` instead of `AnyObject`) and invoke `self.ButtonPress(nil)`. I just tried this and it works.
- Put all the button press function in a separate function, e.g., `performButtonPress()`. Call it from inside the IBAction outlet, and if you want to press the button programatically, directly call `performButtonPress()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Call a button action using the following format: Swift 3**

```
@IBAction func buttonSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Butten clicked")
}
```

To call the button action:

```
let button = UIButton()
self.buttonSelected(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "self" as "sender", example:

```
self.buttonPressed (sender: self)
```

or a simpler version

```
buttonPressed (sender: self)
```

Both tested in Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

```
    lazy var Button : UIBarButtonItem = {
      let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(btnSelection))
      return barButtonItem
    }()


    func btnSelection(){
     // Code
    }

    // Now you can call self.btnSelection() whenever you want
```